# Taking input from touchpad

Tags: python, windows, input, touchpad

Hello everyone  I'm just starting to learn python and I'd like to ask is there any method to receiving input from touchpad? I've seen an Asus laptop with their touchpad become numberpad (Like the photo below) and I'm interested to know if I can do it too but for different purposes. Because I think like this. If I could access certain parts of the touchpad wouldn't it be like I can expand my keyboard to the touchpad that I rarely used ? Thank you for your attention
[image: Attachment]

I have tried to look for some tutorial, video, Library, or even AI assistant like chatgpt or google bard but I can't find any solution to my problem wish anyone can help me to start appreciate your help